# Can't get HP Officejet 6500 card reader to work

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, card-reader

This network (wired) printer works great using the latest HPLIP drivers. However when I plug in an SD card, it just blinks and never shows up mounted anywhere. Has anyone come up with a way to mount these? I'm using Lucid, 10.04.
re: version, hp-info says

```
xxxxx@lucid:~$ hp-info

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.10.5)
Device Information Utility ver. 5.2

Copyright (c) 2001-9 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Using device: hp:/net/Officejet_6500_E709a?zc=HP05857E
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No go on this I'm afraid. [You have to access the card reader over USB](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/353685/comments/1).

> We have removed support for the hp-unload (the card reader). To access the card please use the built in USB mounting system.

Edit: I say that but the `hplip` package still seems to ship `hp-unload`. Try this:

```
hp-unload hp:/net/Officejet_6500_E709a?zc=HP05857E -i
```

Comment: bummer, I don't like the answer but appreciate knowing for sure.

Comment: @Dennis Did you try using hp-unload? It wont let you mount the card but it should let you get files off it through the command line. If it works, it could easily be scripted to semi-automatically grab files.

Comment: I used the command supplied (not something I am familiar with) and got a response something like "no supported device found". The command line and scripting would be easy enough but it seemed like there was no response.