# Access Officejet Pro L7590 memory card reader

Tags: 10.10, nautilus, mount, hp, card-reader

I can't manage to access my printer's memory card reader in Nautilus. I can just access it with `hp-unload`. Here's a sample output from this command:

```
lubuntu@L-X6:~$ hp-unload hp:/net/Officejet_Pro_L7500?zc=HP065193
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.10.6)
Photo Card Access Utility ver. 3.3

Copyright (c) 2001-9 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Using device: hp:/net/Officejet_Pro_L7500?zc=HP065193

|error: Photo card write failed (Card may be write protected)
/
Photocard on device hp:/net/Officejet_Pro_L7500?zc=HP065193 mounted
DO NOT REMOVE PHOTO CARD UNTIL YOU EXIT THIS PROGRAM
warning: Photo card is write protected.
Type 'help' for a list of commands. Type 'exit' to quit.
pcard: / > ls
\
  Name                    Size  Type                          
  dcim/                         directory                     
  eos_digi.tal             0 B  unknown/unknown               
 1 files, 0 B
pcard: / > cd dcim
|pcard: /dcim > ls
|
  Name                    Size  Type                          
  .                             directory                     
  ..                            directory                     
  100eos5d/                     directory                     
  267canon/                     directory                     
  270canon/                     directory                     
  271canon/                     directory                     
  272canon/                     directory                     
 0 files, 0 B
pcard: /dcim > cd 272canon
-pcard: /dcim/272canon > ls
\
  Name                    Size  Type                          
  .                             directory                     
  ..                            directory                     
  _mg_7201.jpg          3.1 MB  image/jpeg                    
...........(some more files).................            
  _mg_7281.jpg          2.5 MB  image/jpeg                    
  _mg_7282.jpg          2.5 MB  image/jpeg                    
 82 files, 241.6 MB (253377883)
```

How can I acess it from nautilus or mount it as a filesystem?

Note that this is similar to this other question: [Can't get HP Officejet 6500 card reader to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2290/cant-get-hp-officejet-6500-card-reader-to-work) but actually there seemed to be no supported device here, while in my case I manage to access the memory card from `hp-unload`.

Update: I haven't been able to point Nautilus to smb://192.168.68.35/memory_card, which is supposed to work, too. Nautilus can't open it.

Update: `nmblookup` and `smbclient` results:

```
lubuntu@L-X6:~$ nmblookup -I 192.168.85.77 -S \*
querying 192.168.85.77 on 127.255.255.255
querying 192.168.85.77 on 192.168.85.255
name_query failed to find name 192.168.85.77
querying * on 127.255.255.255
192.168.85.76 *<00>
Looking up status of 192.168.85.76
    L-X6            <00> -         B <ACTIVE> 
    L-X6            <03> -         B <ACTIVE> 
    L-X6            <20> -         B <ACTIVE> 
    WORKGROUP       <1e> - <GROUP> B <ACTIVE> 
    WORKGROUP       <00> - <GROUP> B <ACTIVE> 

    MAC Address = 00-00-00-00-00-00
```

192.168.85.77 (the printer) did not report anything

```
lubuntu@L-X6:~$ smbclient -L 192.168.85.77
Enter lubuntu's password: 
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[ThreadX] Server=[NQ 4.22]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
Error returning browse list: ERRDOS - ERRnoaccess (Access denied.)
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[ThreadX] Server=[NQ 4.22]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After HOURS of searching and messing with samba configuration, ruining it up, having to reinstall and re-create smb.cnf and several other files, being unable to find the shared resource (Memory_Card) anyhow, I found the (otherwise seeming simple) solution:

```
sudo mkdir /media/HP

sudo mount -t smbfs //192.168.85.77/Memory_Card /media/HP
```

(source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1142804)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `smbclient` and test with different parameters.

For example,

```
nmblookup -I 192.168.1.254 -S \*
```

and then

```
smbclient -L THATNAME
```

Comment: Updated question with results... Apart from that, no notice from printer (192.168.85.77) in the nmblookup results

Comment: 192.168.85.77 does not appear to respond. Is that the valid IP address for the printer? I assume LX-6 is your own computer.